# Get a descending list of items using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistoricoSeries] (
    [IDHistoricoSeries] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IDUtilizador]      INT NOT NULL,
    [codepisodio]       INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_historicoseries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDHistoricoSeries] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_96] FOREIGN KEY ([IDUtilizador]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Utilizadores] ([IDUtilizador]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_hse] FOREIGN KEY ([codepisodio]) REFERENCES [dbo].[EPISODIOS] ([codepisodio])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EPISODIOS] (
    [idepisodio]     INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [codepisodio]    INT          NOT NULL,
    [codserie]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [codtemporada]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [numeroepisodio] INT          NOT NULL,
    [tituloepisodio] VARCHAR (53) NOT NULL,
    [duracaominutos] INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([codepisodio] ASC)
);
```

These are my table definitions.

```
string maisVistoEpisodio = "SELECT * FROM EPISODIOS WHERE EPISODIOS.codepisodio IN (SELECT codepisodio, count(codepisodio) AS mais_vistos FROM HISTORICOSERIES GROUP BY codepisodio ORDER BY COUNT (codepisodio) DESC)";
```

This is my SQL Server query that i've been from quite sometime hacking away with no results.

My end goal was to have a listing of the most watched episodes from the table EPISODIOS, but the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

arose itself and I don't know how to fix.

Can anyone shed a bit of light?
Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And please explain what "most watched" has to do with the data.

Comment: A `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)` sub-query must return a **single column** but your sub-query returns two columns.

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` instead of `WHERE IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  If so, you can use `TOP WITH TIES` in the subquery:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM EPISODIOS E
WHERE E.codepisodio IN (SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES HS.codepisodio
                        FROM HISTORICOSERIES HS
                        GROUP BY HS.codepisodio
                        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                       )
```

Comment: TIL I learned about "`TOP WITH TIES`" - now I want there to be a `TOP WITH BOWTIES` and `TOP WITH TURTLENECKS`, oh well.

Comment: Indeed it is sqlserver. "Top with ties" is unknown to me, but that's learning! Will try asap and post back.

Comment: This is perfect! Never I'd get there on my own! Thanks!